# CentOS 7 - Rsyslog error7

Tags: centos, rsyslog

My syslog server does not write messages correctly, traffic capture shows me 100 events, but the file in /var/log/xxx.log only 50 or 60

Have

rsyslogd 7.4.7, compiled with:
        FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
        FEATURE_LARGEFILE:                      No
        GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
        FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
        32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
        uuid support:                           Yes

My rule is

```
if $fromhost-ip=='172.25.104.11' then /var/log/software_ges.log
&~
```

Comment: You might try prefixing the filename with a minus sign, `-`, so that it does not sync the file after every write. (I think this applies to the form of syntax you have).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I have tried this configuration but I am still missing messages.

Comment: There's a lot of rsyslog documentation on [queues](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/concepts/queues.html), and [statistics](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/rsyslog_statistic_counter.html) you need to read to determine where the messsages are being dropped. You can also configure [omfile](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/omfile.html) to use a separate thread, bigger buffers and so on. It is all quite complex and I am no expert. Perhaps try single simple steps and post separate questions on what you did and what happened.